# Are Turbogears2 apps deployable in Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku, deployment, turbogears, turbogears2

I have been googling quite a bit about this topic but have found pretty much nothing about it.

Does any body know if it is possible to deploy Turbogears2 apps to Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an Heroku tutorial on the documentation of the upcoming 2.3.1 version, but it works also with current 2.3.0 release:

http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/development/cookbook/deploy/heroku.html